# selecting the first and last 10 rows of a sql query

Tags: sql, sqlite

hi i have a sqlite database like this

```
price   category_id product_id
100000  89  1
2000    88  2
50000   89  3
```

i want to extract the top and last 5 of product id for each category (the highest and lowest products of each category)

i have written this

```
SELECT *
FROM sql_data_users.products
GROUP BY product_id,category_id
ORDER BY price ASC
LIMIT 10
```

but it gives me 10 rows instead of 10*len(category_id)
also for the solution to be complete i thought of adding another query and changeing the order to ASC  and then uniting the 2 query is that possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by price asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by price desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_asc <= 5 or seqnum_desc <= 5
order by category, price desc;
```

Comment: this seems to be working thank u can u explain it a bit?

Comment: @Cenasha'bani . . . `row_number()` enumerates the rows -- the two calls returns sequence numbers both ascending and descending per `category`.  The `where` selects 5 from each.